# Given a linear regression model with p predictors why is p the lower bound on the number of sample observations we need?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, supervised-learning, parameterization

Working through notes that say the following:

Given the linear model:
$$Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X1+...+\beta_pXp$$
we need to collect at least n=p sample observations to infer the values of the parameters.

I can very vaguely see why it would make sense to have at least p observations as we have p features, but what is the actual reason for this?

Comment: There are many levels of complexity that can satisfactorily answer this question. Would an answer based on singular/degenerate square matrices suffice to you?

Comment: You need as many equations as unknowns for the system to be defined.  If you have less equations, then there is no single answer, the answers are functions not values.  If you want to find the equation of a line, and you only have one point, then there are an infinite number of lines going through that point.  You need two points to define the line.  A higher version of that is what is going on.  For real world data there is noise, so I suggest no less than 5 points for every parameter.  I prefer 30 points, 300 points, or 40,000 points, but not 40M points because it becomes compute heavy/slow.

Comment: Sorry for the double.  There are 5 ways to communicate a mathematical idea: algebraic/symbols, words, flowcharts, graphs, and number-tables.  Mileage in the mode varies depending on the purpose.  The "two points define a line" is good for a linear model in 2 dimensions, and as you go to p dimensions you still need p points to define that line.

Comment: @Firebug, the simplest answer would be great at the moment but I would also like to know the others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is purely mathematical. Given a linear model,
$$Y=X\beta+\varepsilon$$
where $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the response vector and $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ is the predictor matrix. Then the linear regression model has an exact solution that can be computed as,
$$
\hat\beta = (X^tX)^{-1}X^tY
$$

- If $n>p$ this solution works just fine.
- If $n<p$ the result from this operation $(X^tX)$ is not inversible and thus in these situations  the term $(X^tX)^{-1}$  **cannot** be computed. For this reason, in $n<p$ frameworks we cannot solve a simple linear regression model.

Just as a comment, as a solution to these problem, there are many alternatives of what is called penalized regression, that add a penalization term to the regression equation making possible to obtain a solution even if $n<p$. If you are interested on this, I would recommend you having a look to ridge regression and lasso regression.